# What would happen if we supply dc as well as ac voltage in a circuit?

Tags: power, ac

How the characteristics of the circuit will change if we supply some dc voltage in an ac circuit ?

Comment: you get ac with a dc offset

Comment: In question it is given that we have supplied both ac and dc voltage to a circuit containing resistors, capacitors and inductors. Now, i want to know how we can solve this kind of problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would happen if we supply dc as well as ac voltage in a circuit?

You'll get an alternating voltage with a DC offset. Half or full-wave rectified AC supplies without smoothing capacitors fall into this category.

If you add a smoothing capacitor you get DC with AC ripple. That also falls into your category.

> How the characteristics of the circuit will change if we supply some dc voltage in an ac circuit ?

Some systems won't like it. Your loudspeaker, for example, doesn't like a DC component as it offsets the speaker coil in one direction. Your smartphone wouldn't like the charger voltage to go negative (large AC component).

Why are you asking?

Comment: So, will current also contain some dc components or not ?

Comment: Your original question says it will, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the schematics I've been studying for radio transceivers, this is sometimes useful. DC can be used to amplify the RF/AC signal. This, of course, assumes your schematic is designed for this purpose. Inductors can be used to keep DC out of the areas you don't wish it to be in and capacitors can be used to block AC from other areas keeping your circuit clear. I believe this schematic I found accurately represents that.

[image]